# how to get null value from mysql any_value() function

Tags: mysql

I want to select the newest data from mysql, so I run the below sql, but I get the `next_visit_time` is not matching the real value of row of  the max `create_time`. So I check the data, and i found the newest data is `null` , so I guest Mysql is not going to get null value when using any_value function. 
How to get the any_value() if the value is null?

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    max(created_time) as created_time,
    any_value(next_visit_time) as next_visit_time 
FROM
    student_visit_record
GROUP BY
    student_id
```

Comment: Question why are you using `ANY_VALUE()`? Because `next_visit_time` doesnt sound like a column containing the same data for very record for the grouped student_id.. `ANY_VALUE()` only makes sense if you know all values with in that column for a group are the same..

Comment: *next_visit_time is not matching the real value of row of the max create_time* - of course not. Why should it?

Comment: Why are you using an alias when you have no joins? It just adds more code for no purpose

Comment: Maybe I did not clarify the question. I expected the result columns which contain the max `created_time` will get the `next_visit_time` of the same row of the max `created_time` .@juergend

Comment: @NoOorZ24 hhaaaa, that's right , thanks for your advice

Comment: So how to write the sql to meet my need if the `next_visit_time` will be null ? @RaymondNijland

Comment: You need to write a subquery where you group by student_id  and find the max off created_time and inner self join that result with the table student_visit_record.. Then you will find matching next_visit_time records with the group.. Alot off questions already exists here asking the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  student_id,
  max(created_time),
  next_visit_time 
FROM
  student_visit_record
WHERE
  next_visit_time IS NOT NULL OR next_visit_time IS NULL
GROUP BY
  student_id
```

Could this be what you're looking for by any chance? [See SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fd868/1/0)

Comment: Didn't you want the newest data of your records, even if next_visit_time is null? What I'm doing is returning your rows whether next_visit_time has a value or not. Or what is it you're looking for then?

Comment: because the next_visit_time is not in the group by statement, this sql will fail to execute.

Comment: No, it will not fail.

Comment: You can do order by student_id asc; as well if you simply just want to sort by the student's id's, or order by next_visit_time desc; if you want. However you desire to sort your data.

Comment: if you want the newest entry, no matter the field, you can add another row that inserts CURRENT_TIMESTAMP upon update, and sort by that. That can be set to be done automatically by the database. Order by replacing the group by statement in these cases of course.